# Defering java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to defer the following script. I need it to **launch only after Keyup** (aftet the mouse was clicked then I start typing). this is delaying page load I specially want to delay jquery.js.. see script below..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jQuery.js"></script>
<script defer type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchquery").keyup(function(){
        $.get("suggest.php", {searchquery: $(this).val()}, function(data){
            $("datalist").empty();
            $("datalist").html(data);
        }); 
    }); 
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchquery2").keyup(function(){
        $.get("suggest1.php", {searchquery2: $(this).val()}, function(data){
            $("datalist").empty();
            $("datalist").html(data); 
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think that `.keyup()` isn't fired when the user click the mouse, but when the user release a keyboard key. To listen to the mouse click event you must use `.mousedown()` instead.

Comment: Or use the `.click()` event.

Comment: Put the `<script>` at the end of your HTML.

Comment: Tiago yes its true but I first must click by mouse then I start typing.

Comment: But if you **don't** click by mouse and start typing the event will be fired anyway. Why don't you listen to the correct event?

Comment: Yes tiago. I need to defer it to after I click then start typing or befor I start typing. :)

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable method for deferring scripts seems to be to insert a `<script>` element into the page at runtime. If you're deferring things like jQuery, then you'll probably want to load them once the DOM is loaded rather than when the user performs an action, which will typically get your script loaded sooner and probably give better performance to the user (e.g. when they first click something, they won't have to wait for jQuery to load before something awesome happens).

Below is an example of loading a script in about the same way as Google Analytics. If your browser supports the JS API I'm using, and the events I'm listening to, **and** `console.log()`, then you should see that `window.jQuery` is logged as `undefined` when the page loads, and then a function five seconds later (as long as jQuery loads by then!).

**Disclaimer:** Absolutely nothing has been done here to ensure cross-browser compatibility. This is just a simple demonstration of deferring a script.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
            (function() {

                function init() {
                    loadDeferredScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js');
                    console.log(window.jQuery);
                    setTimeout(function() { console.log(window.jQuery); }, 5000);
                }

                function loadDeferredScript(src) {
                    var script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.src = src;
                    var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                    firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, firstScript);
                }

                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```